Choosing an ordered triplet of non-negative integers $(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ such that $m_1 + m_2 + m_3 = n$.
Define
$$A = \{ (m_1, m_2, m_3) : m_1 \geq 0, m_2 \geq 0, m_3 \geq 0, m_1 + m_2 + m_3 = n\}$$
Given that $n \geq 0$ and $n, m_1, m_2, m_3 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then why it is the case that
$$\vert A \vert = \binom{n+2}{2}?$$
In particular, does this problem admit a conventional interpretation in terms binomial coefficients that I may have missed?
Because whilst I can 'see' why we are choosing a size-$2$ subset, I cannot 'see' why it's from a set of $n+2$ distinct elements.

My reasoning.
In the text I am working from this is stated without any working, so I'm assuming it's meant to be an elementary computation.
As I understand, the question asks for the number of ordered triplets $(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ which obey the constraint that $m_1 + m_2 + m_3 = n$.
As this didn't at all seem obvious to me, I tried some case bashing and found that as an example, for $n = 3$, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
A = \{&(3, 0, 0), (0,3,0) (2, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0); \\
&(2, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1); \\
&(1, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2); \\
&(0, 0, 3)\}
\end{align*}$$
I noted that $m_3$ is a 'residual' in the sense of not being a free variable. It is fully determined by a choice of $n$ and a valid choice of $(m_1, m_2)$, with $m_3 = n - m_1 - m_2$.
Hence I have organised the above triplets by row, with the top row of triplets with $m_3 = 0$, second row with $m_3 = 1$ etc.
Rewriting the condition again, I have $n - m_3 = m_1 + m_2$.
This suggested that I should fix $n = \bar{n}$, and for each integer value $0 \leq m_3 \leq \bar{n}$ can take, list valid choices of $(m_1, m_2)$.
For each integer value of $m_3$, then we have to consider pairs $(m_1, m_2)$ of numbers between $0$ and $\bar{n} - m_3$ that sum to $\bar{n}$.
At every integer value of $m_3$, there are $(\bar{n} - m_3) + 1$ such pairs $(m_1, m_2)$.
Summing across all integer values $m_3$ can take, we have that
$$\vert A \vert = \sum^{\bar{n}}_{m_3 = 0} (\bar{n} - m_3) + 1$$
Because $0 \leq \bar{n} - m_3 \leq \bar{n}$, and the above sequence is descending, this can be rewritten as an ascending sequence
$$\vert A \vert = \sum^{\bar{n}}_{m_3 = 0} m_3 + 1 = 1 + 2 + \dots + (\bar{n} + 1).$$
This is just the sum of the integers from 1 to $(\bar{n} + 1)$. Dropping the requirement that $\bar{n}$ is fixed, we have
$$\vert A \vert = T_{n+1} = \binom{(n+1) + 1}{2} = \binom{n+2}{2}.$$
That is, the cardinality of the set is the $n+1$-th triangular number.
Now I can 'see' the bottom of the binomial coefficient in that we are choosing two elements $(m_1, m_2)$ such that $m_1 + m_2 = n - m_3$, but I can't 'see' why we are choosing two elements from $n+2$ objects.

See Stars and Bars

@lulu. Thank you for this, it definitively answers my question. I will post a solution to my own question when I've finished reading it.
